# How do i return an object when closing a form

Tags: c#

I want to return an object of type `Period` when my dialog form (windows form application) closes.

I know that you can create simple properties `string` or `int` or something similar, that can be accessed with `form.property` when the result came back with `OK`. The thing is that `Period` consists of a `List`, two `DateTime`, a `string` and three `decimal` properties.

If i try to make a `Period` property i get the error message `CS0053 Inconsistent accessibility: property type 'Period' is less accessible than property 'NewPeriod.Period'`. But i don't really believe that i have to return that object in parts and make a property for every single property in `Period`.

Also when trying to make a `List<Entry>` property i get the same `CS0053` error, although with `Entry` instead of `Period`. `Entry` consists of four `string`, one `double` and one `DateTime` property.

Here is my shortened DialogForm:

```
public partial class NewPeriod : Form
    {
        public Period Period { get; set; }

        private void btn_ok_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("OK");
            Period = behind.AddPeriod(dtp_begin.Value, dtp_end.Value, num_invoiceAmount.Value);
        }
    }
```

This is the `Period` model class:

```
class Period
    {
        public List<Entry> Entries { get; set; }
        public DateTime Begin { get; set; }
        public DateTime End { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public decimal ServerInvoiceAmount { get; set; }
        public decimal SplitCostAmount { get; set; }
        public decimal DonationAmount { get; set; }
    }
```

I want to use the result like this:

```
var newPeriodForm = new NewPeriod();
var result = newPeriodForm.ShowDialog();
if(result == DialogResult.OK)
{
    periods.Add(newPeriodForm.Period);
}
```

This is the first time im writing something in C# completely on my own and i couldn't find anything more than returning simple properties while researching.

Comment: "I want to use the result like this". Is there a reason why you *cannot* use the result like that? I mean, that should work.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen yeah as i wrote i get a error message. But as Caius Jard pointed out my `Period` class is not public

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See where you wrote

```
class Period
```

Write this instead:

```
public class Period
```

Omitting the word "public" means it defaults to "internal", which in turn means you can't make a public property out of it, because "internal" is not as "widely visible" an access level as "public". You can downgrade accessibility (make something "less visible") but you can't upgrade it - if the class was public your property could be internal, protected, private etc but not the other way round.

As a new developer, if you're not sure what to put, just make all your classes public. Eventually you'll start to use other access levels (in various places) as situations crop up where you need the facility, but right now I'd say save yourself the headache of dealing with arcane compiler messages and use public for classes and properties, and private for fields

Comment: Thanks! I completely ignored the fact that classes public/private/etc... I come from java and there all classes are public by default if you create a new one.

Comment: Oh.. I thought java was somewhat similar to C# (package-private which is like C#'s internal).. Welcome to C#!

Comment: it is similar in java you just don't need to think about this because your ide automatically makes the class public. Thanks!